# Special representation of polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How to prove that for natural $n$ the polynomial $(x^4-6x^2+1)^n$ can't be represented in such a way 
 $$
 (x^4-6x^2+1)^n=f(x)^2+1,  (x^4-6x^2+1)^n=g(x)^3-1, 
 $$
  where$f(x), g(x)$  are polynomials.

Seems, for  $n=2k$ I can prove it for the first  case. We have
  $$
  1=f(x)^2-(x^4-6x^2+1)^{2k}=(f(x)-(x^4-6x^2+1)^{k})(f(x)+(x^4-6x^2+1)^{k}).
  $$
  Thus $f(x)-(x^4-6x^2+1)^{k}=c, f(x)+(x^4-6x^2+1)^{k}=c^{-1}$ or $f(x)-(x^4-6x^2+1)^{k}=-c, f(x)+(x^4-6x^2+1)^{k}=-c^{-1}$ for some constant $c.$  It is easy to show that this leads to a contradiction.

How it may be proved for  case $n=2k+1$ and for the second case $(x^4-6x^2+1)^n=g(x)^3-1.$?

Comment: I don't get your first proof...why should it all be equal to 1 or -1?

Comment: if product of two polynomials is a constant the they are constant too

Comment: ok but why 1? one could be equal to 3 and the other to 1/3...

Comment: yes, you are right. I have corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $F(x)=(x^4-6x^2+1)^n-1$ is the square of some polynomial for some positive integer $n$. Then $F(x)$ has a zero at $x_0$ only if $F'(x_0)=0$ as well. But $F(x)=0$ for $x=\pm \sqrt{6}$, whereas $$F'(\pm \sqrt{6})=\bigg[4nx(x^2-3)(x^4-6x^2+1)^{n-1}\bigg]_{x=\pm\sqrt{6}}=\pm 12n\sqrt{6}\neq 0$$

for any positive integer $n$. Hence $F(x)$ is not the square of a polynomial.

Can you generalize this to the cubic case?

Comment: What about another zero of $F'(x):$ $x=0?$ In this case we have that $F(0)=1^n-1=0.$ So $x=0$ is a common root of $F(x)$ and $F'(x)$.

Comment: @Leox: Consider the polynomial $p(x)=x^2(x-1)$ with first derivative $p'(x)=(3x-2)x$. On the one hand, these have zero as a common root and thus $x=0$ is a double root of $p(x)$. But $p'(x)$ also has $x=2/3$ as a zero, which is not the case for $p(x)$. So at least one factor in $p(x)$ does not appear twice, so it can't  be the square of a polynomial. In other words, it's not enough to find one double root; _all_ the roots must occur with even multiplicity.

Comment: @Leox: Fixed the error in my argument. (The correct statement is that, if $F(x_0)=0$, then $x_0$ has multiplicity greater than one only if $F(x_0)=0$ as well; my error was in implying that the converse was also true.)

Comment: What about the cubic case? To solve it  I need to find a   root of the polynomial $(x^4-6x^2+1)^n+1$ for all $n$ but I cant do it. Any hint?

Comment: Hrm. You're right, that cubic case is trickier than I realized. I think the right line of argument uses the fact that $f'(x)$ has zeros at $z=\pm \sqrt{3}$ which $f''(z)$ lacks; however, I haven't managed to _entirely_ convince myself that $f'(x_0)=0$ only if $f''(x_0)=0$.

Comment: well..in this case we can easy find all roots of $F'(x)$ and check out that none of them is  a root of $F(x).$This is enougth to prove all we need. Thank you!

Comment: Not entirely sure that works (though I might just being too cautious). An argument which I've been able to convince myself of is this: If $f(x)$ is the cube of a polynomial, then every root of $f'(x)$ must have multiplicity at least two. (More precisely, it can have multiplicity 2, 5, 8, ...). But if every root of $f'(x)$ is a double root, then we're in the same situation as in the squared case. So it'll be enough to find a root of $f'(x)$ which isn't a root of $f''(x)$.